# /etc/init startup script in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: init

How can I use /etc/init to run scripts on startup in Ubuntu 14.04?
File: minecraft.conf in /etc/init

```
respawn limit 20 5
cd /home/minecraft
java -Xmx2048M -Xms2048M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui
```

There's no logs on reboot, or else I'd love to share them.

Comment: forgot to mention;
cd /home/minecraft
java -Xmx2048M -Xms2048M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui

will run the jar as expected.

Comment: `cd` should be [`chdir`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#chdir).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need file-system to navigate directory before starting init script so use like

```
start on local-filesystems
```

or 
if your jar need networking should be working at the time of starting or running init task then use like

```
start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE!=lo)
```

or

```
start on (local-filesystem and started networking)
```

instead of

```
start on runlevel [2345]
```

and 
better to use like:

```
java -Xmx2048M -Xms2048M -jar /home/minecraft/minecraft_server.jar nogui
```

or

```
cd /home/minecraft && java -Xmx2048M -Xms2048M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui
```

learn more about upstart from [Upstart Ubuntu cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#start-on)